# How to speed up a recursive CTE

Tags: sql, t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Given the following recursive CTE (simplified a bit for my example):

```
    WITH myCTE (sort, parentid, myid, level, somedata)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT 
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.myid) as decimal(38, 20)) as sort,
        o.parentid, 
        o.myid, 
        0 as level, 
        o.somedata
    FROM 
        table1 t1,
        table2 t1,
        datatable o
    WHERE t1.somebool = 1 AND t2.id = t1.foreignid and o.foreignkey = t2.key
        and o.parentid = ''
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT
        CAST(b.sort + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY o.myid) / power(10.0, b.level + 1)) as decimal(38, 20)) as sort,
        o.parentid, 
        o.myid, 
        b.level + 1, 
        o.somedata
    FROM datatable o
    INNER JOIN myCTE AS b
        ON o.parentid = b.myid
```

The general idea is as follows: Starting with a selection of items based on table1 and table2, I want to start up the query and in the anchor I want to find all the data with no parent, join it with data that has the main items and parents and keep digging until I found all the data. I'm dealing with a tree of unknown depth although the max level I have found is 7.

Is it useful to apply extra restrictions to the recursive member? It seems to work better the more restrictions I copy over from the anchor, but wouldn't just filtering on "o.parentid = b.myid" be sufficient for it?

Comment: Is `datatable.parentid` indexed? Does the execution plan use the index?

Comment: Is it possible for you to give us the execution plan? If you don't know how you can take a look at this : http://plixa.nl/how-to-read-query-execution-plans/ With the execution plan there is much more to say :)

Comment: Sadly, I have no rights to look at the execution plan. :( But datatable.parentid is not indexed on its own. However, it's indexed as part of a governing index, will try to see if I can trigger that one somehow.

Comment: Hitting the right index seemed to do the trick. I listed all the columns from the index in my select and (after caching I suppose) it now runs in 1 sec.

Comment: Okay, in the end it didn't prove to be the answer and we decided to just do one big single flat select and do the tree-ordering in code instead of launching 10000's of select-queries to the server.

Comment: What data type is parentid? (var)char? Why do you order by myid? What indicator of order is an ID?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a debugging / tuning approach I would recommend:

1)  Add the following query hint to rule out the possibility that there's an infinite loop.

```
...
)
SELECT  parentid ,
        myid ,
        [level]
FROM myCTE 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)
```

2)  If that returns results, then try the same query with the query hint commented out. It should run in about the same time and return the same number of results.

3)  At this point you should add back the sort field.  Unless there is a specific requirement to include it in the recursion I would recommend you move it to the Query against the CTE, like so.

```
...
)
SELECT  parentid ,
        myid ,
        [level],
        -- I'm not sure what this accomplishes:
        -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(myid) ASC) / CAST (POWER(10,level) AS DECIMAL(38,20)) AS sort
        -- Wouldn't this look nicer?
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [level] ASC, CAST ([parentid] AS INT) ASC, CAST ([myid] AS INT) ASC) AS sort

FROM myCTE 
ORDER BY [sort]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 20)
```

3)  Finally, add back in your joins on Table1 and Table2.  I would encourage you to add it to the CTE query as well.

I realize you have a workaround, but I'd appreciate it if you take the time to see if my approach works for you.